Are there any links between descriptive set theory and computational complexity theory?
In descriptive set theory, we are concerned with classifying sets of reals (more generally, subsets of Polish spaces) by the complexity of their definitions, and from this, we obtain structures like the Borel hierarchy ($\Sigma^0_n$, $\Pi^0_n$, and $\Delta^0_n$, etc...), and the projective hierarchy (which extends Borel sets to projections, contains coanalytic sets, and so on).
I am wondering if any descriptive set-theoretic classifications of complexity correspond in a natural way to classifications of computational complexity -- say the complexity of computing a certain set of reals by the BSS model of computation, for example. Are there any ways to draw parallels between positions sets might have on descriptive set-theoretic hierarchies, and complexity hierarchies defined for models of real computation? Perhaps effective descriptive set theory plays a role here?

Sure! Here's a whole book about it.

Looking at the preface and the table of contents, it seems to me that descriptive set theory doesn't play a role in the descriptive complexity framework. Am I wrong?

@the_tomato: I've added a comment to address that question.
